# Do these light switches have neutral wires?

Tags: electrical, neutral

My house was built in 1979.

I know that certain smart light switches like [Kasa](https://amzn.to/3Cnjt7w) require a neutral wire.

[Here I have photos of 2 light switches](https://photos.app.goo.gl/S3Ze4rtFjzj5m9kh6) (3 photos of the first, and 2 photos of the second).

Do either of those have a neutral?

Comment: Those look like vanilla light switches to me.  They switch the "hot" wire on and off, and don't care about the neutral.

Comment: Hard to tell from the photos, but if there is a white wire connected to those switches, then no neutral.  If there is white wires just connected to each other or just capped/wire nutted by itself then neutral.  Neutral must be white or grey, but white might not be neutral(should have black tape/paint on it).  79 having neutral at a switch is very lucky, was not required back then.  Saved a lot of money.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for your comment! I just ran out to Home Depot and bought a NCVT and then was able to add a short video of each switch if you have a moment to let me know what you think of the fuller view. Thanks!

Comment: Please _carefully_ pull all the wires out of the box for the 2nd switch and take pictures that show us which cable each wires leads into. Also, it makes it much easier for everyone if you simply embed the images directly in your question instead of providing external links. Especially since you'll eventually run out of cloud storage space and delete these pics meaning that this question will no longer be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you do have neutral coming into this box, it's the two white wires with the red wire nut, pointed to by the red arrow. You would connect the neutral of your new smart switch to this pair of wires.

[image: annotated screen shot from OPs photos]

BTW- the green arrow points to the ground wires. The electrician put a crimp on the grounds and left a tail sticking out that's attached to the ground on this switch. You would remove the ground from this switch and using an appropriately sized wire nut, connect it to the ground from your new smart switch.

For the other switch, **this is illegal**!

[image: two wires under the side screw]

This type of screw down connection is not UL listed for two wires under the single screw. These should have been joined with a third wire in a wire nut, then the third wire connected under this screw.

Additionally, this grounding wire connection is not satisfactory:

[image: poor ground wire connection]

Wires must be connected using an approved connector (such as a wire nut, crimp, or lever-lock connector). Simply wrapping a new wire around the old doesn't meet code. Additionally, the fact that the old ground wires are covered in paint means you've got an even worse connection.

This second switch does also seem to have neutral in the box (the red arrow):

[image: screen cap of 2nd switch showing bundle of neutral wires]

Note that white wire in the green circle. It appears that it's smaller than the other two wires in that bundle. To me, it appears that there's one #14 AWG wire in a bundle with 2 #12 AWG wires. This may or *may not* be OK. If the breaker protecting these wires is rated at 15A (on the end of the handle), you're just fine. If it's rated at 20A, then that #14 wire is *not* OK. If it's actually the same size as the other wires and just appears that way in your video, then it's likely not an issue (I would presume that the original electrician used the proper size wiring for the breaker, but it's always good to check).

The red wire on this switch indicates one of two things:

1. This switch is part of a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC). When you turned off the breaker for this switch (you did shut off the breaker before pulling the switches out of the wall, right?), you *should* have thrown two breakers that had a handle tie between them forcing you to shut off both at the same time. You'd find that one of the breakers had a black wire attached to it and the other had a red wire and that both of those wires led into the same sheath as the cable exits the panel.

   It's possible, since your house was built in 1979, that these two breakers are *not* handle tied, since I don't believe that was a code requirement then. However, if you only shut off one breaker, say the one with the black wire, there will still be power to the red wire and you'll still get zapped!

   It may require taking the dead front (the panel cover) off of your panel box to actually look at the wiring attached to the breaker to confirm that this is a MWBC. **Please** use *extreme* caution when you have the panel cover off - you're exposing yourself to 240V at 100-200A and could easily kill yourself. If you're not comfortable with this, it would be worthwhile having a pro come in and identify & handle tie all the MWBCs for you.
2. This switch is part of a modern switch loop - one that provides neutral at the switch (as pointed out in a comment by Manasseh Katz in a comment, below). In this case, the power comes to the light fixture at the ceiling. Like this:

   [image: 3-wire switch loop]
   <sup>Image found via internet search. Was posted in another [diy] answer somewhere</sup>

   To determine if this is part of a switch loop, with the power still off remove (one of) the ceiling lights that this switch operates. If you see a /3 cable (white, black, red, ground) then this is a switch loop.

In either case, the clean black, white and ground wires seem to lead to a cable exiting the bottom right of the box. This appears to be a retrofit cable (after the wall was painted, thus painting the original wiring). Whatever this cable leads to is also switched by this switch, so it should be reasonably easy to find.

Comment: One important correction: *The red wire on this switch would indicate that this switch is part of a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC).* I doubt that here. If it were red because of MWBC, it would be incoming hot. In which case it would be the one tied to "another hot", but there are two blacks for that on the switch. Which means red is *switched hot*. Which means something like: black (hot)/white (neutral)/red (switched hot in the other direction) coming from the fixture. Or to put it another way: A switch loop but modern so neutral included at the switch box. DV not from me. I'll +1 after fix.

Comment: I see your point, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, however, to my eye, it's very difficult to tell for certain. The clean black wire from the switch appears to also be #14 and goes into a cable leading out the bottom right of the box, while the thicker, painted black leads into the wire nut. To be sure, I would think that some additional pictures (not video) of the wiring of this switch would be most helpful.

Comment: I do appreciate your comments, but I would _really_ appreciate a comment from our phantom down voter to indicate what else might be wrong with this. Hard to fix it if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Oh, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, I get you now. I'll update.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a switch that both is a switch loop and also feeds power, switched or unswitched on to another  point.  Nothing wrong with it I suppose, just very unusual.  Manasseh / Freeman ... have you seen that done?   Very easy to figure this out with a little testing so I think this is a good answer.  I didn't downvote but maybe it's a little TMI for the basic question.

Comment: Can't say that I've seen it myself, @jay613, but it can and, apparently, has been done.

Comment: Holy smokes... this answer is scaring me. I only flipped one breaker. It was not 2 breakers joined together. I used this [Klein Tools NCVT1P Non-Contact Voltage Detector Pen](https://amzn.to/3QJhv5V) before and after flipping the breaker. It chirped before but not after, so I figured I was safe. Was I incorrect? I [feel like](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/255193/20576) I should either always shut off the main breaker to the whole house or not trying any electrical work because I definitely don't want to get zapped.

Comment: @Ryan Please see point #2 on the red wire. That was a strong likelihood before, and, now that you've confirmed that there wasn't a "ping" from your NCV it's the most likely candidate. It _never_ hurts to be extra careful around electricity, but it's not terrifying if you're careful and cautious.

Comment: @FreeMan I also meant to say thank you SO MUCH for your incredibly detailed answer. I hadn't even realized the complexity of what I was asking about. Both switches in my videos control wall sockets. I wish these rooms had ceiling lights, but they don't, so I'm thinking of installing smart switches that will be able to turn on multiple smart outlets, which lamps will be plugged into. I can open up the wall sockets later tonight. It sounds like I'll need to hire an electrician anyway for reconfiguring the illegal one since I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: No need to hire someone to fix that, @Ryan. It's a simple matter of making proper pigtails. [Here](https://www.thespruce.com/make-pigtail-wire-connections-1152879) is one simple article/video I found in a search for "electrical pigtail" - there were a multitude of others. I found no issues with what they did in this video.

Comment: @FreeMan I will check it out! Thanks so much!